Krusader vs. Double Commander in Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS
Having used Krusader in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS, I looked for it in KDE Discover in Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS. When I didn't find it I installed Double Commander instead.  However, the Double Commander version installed was 1.11 beta in GTK2, whose GUI was barely usable in KDE Plasma.
Despite not finding Krusader in Discover, I tried installing it from the command line:
apt install krusader

Much to my surprise that worked, but Discover still doesn't find Krusader, even though i't already installed.
Now that I have Krusader working, I used Discover to remove Double Commander.  Unfortunately, that did not remove Double Commander from my "Favorites", nor can I now remove it with the customary right-click.

The OS obviously has the needed repository for Krusader configured. Why doesn't Discover know it?
How can I get rid of the Double Commander entry in my Favorites? Do I have to reinstall it to get rid of the entry?


To answer question #2, using Discover to reinstall Double Commander removed it from Favorites without my needing to do anything else.  I then used Discover to remove it again. ;-)

Discover's preferences can show the repositories it is using. Is it utilizing the official repositories?

I wouldn't know which are the "official repositories" but I have to assume that a freshly installed OS would have them configured.
